# App crash `ImageIO_DataIsNotReadable` when creating UIImage with data

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiimage

I get some crash reports in the following code when fetching images from a server:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).async {

    if
        let imageData = try? imageFile.getData(), // This gets the image data from the server
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData) { // This is where the crash seems to happen
        //...
    }
}
```

The crash report:

```
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   ImageIO                              0x0000000184c3bef0 ERROR_ImageIO_DataIsNotReadable(unsigned char*) + 16
1   ImageIO                              0x0000000184c3bd90 IIOImageSource::doBindToReader() + 280
2   ImageIO                              0x0000000184c3c180 IIOImageSource::updatedCount() + 48
3   ImageIO                              0x0000000184c40040 CGImageSourceGetCount + 152
4   UIKit                                0x000000018c32c29c _UIImageRefFromData + 396
5   UIKit                                0x000000018c49d608 -[UIImage(UIImagePrivate) _initWithData:preserveScale:cache:] + 120
6   MyApp                               0x0000000100fd60d0 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed, Arg[1] = Owned To Guaranteed> of closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 (Any?, Swift.Error?) -> () in MyApp.MyClass.myFunction(forUser: MyApp.User) -> () (MyClass.swift:0)
7   MyApp                               0x0000000100fdba10 partial apply forwarder for closure #1 () -> () in closure #1 (Any?, Swift.Error?) -> () in MyApp.MyClass.myFunction(forUser: MyApp.User) -> () (MyClass.swift:0)
8   MyApp                               0x00000001010a90a4 reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_owned () -> () to @callee_unowned @convention(block) () -> () (MyController.swift:0)
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000182692a54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x0000000182692a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
11  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018269fea4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1028
12  libdispatch.dylib                    0x000000018269fa38 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 116
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018293b06c _pthread_wqthread + 1264
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018293ab6c start_wqthread + 0
```

I am not able to reproduce the crash but I have two guesses:

- `UIImage(data:)` is executed on a background thread. There are ongoing discussions about whether UIImage being of UIKit is thread safe. However the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage) now more clearly suggest that `UIImage` is thread safe:

  > "The immutable nature of image objects also means that they are safe
  >   to create and use from any thread."
- The image data is corrupted in a way that causes an exception that is not caught within the creation of `UIImage`. And because among many images only a few have corrupted data I could not reproduce the crash. Maybe there is a data test that I should do manually before trying to create an `UIImage` from it.

Can anyone interpret the crash report?

Comment: Did you find some kind of solution for this? I'm having a similar problem with my app

Comment: @halfblood17 I haven’t, crashes still occur. If you find a solution, please share.

Comment: For now I only figured out that the cause (at least for me) is indeed a corrupted image. I checked inside my app bundle and the image that caused the crashed had no data inside (0KB). So I tried crashing the app on purpose, adding the same file to my bundle and loading a UIImage directly from it but there was no crash and all i got was this error "BOMStream BOMStreamWithFileAndSys(int, off_t, size_t, int, char *, BomSys *): read: No such file or directory" so I'm still unable to reproduce it.